# How to use RobotFramework to choose date from datepicker

Tags: automated-tests, integration-testing, robotframework

I want to write script test frontend by RobotFramework but I don't know how to choose a date in Datepicker calendar by RobotFramework.

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide more information on what you have tried and which part of your solution is not producing desired results. Please also read the SO guidelines before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To choose date on datepicker create following keywords:

```
Select Datepicker Date
    [Documentation]     Select given day from datepicker
    [Arguments]     ${dateElem}     ${expectedMonthYear}    ${clickElement}
    Input Text  ${dateElem}    ${Empty}    # open the datepicker
    ${monthyear}=   Get Datepicker MonthYear
    :FOR    ${Index}    IN RANGE    1   31
    \   Run Keyword If  '${monthyear}' == '${expectedMonthYear}'   Exit For Loop
    \   Click Link    //*/div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']//*/a[contains(@class, 'ui-datepicker-prev')]
    \   ${monthyear}=   Get Datepicker MonthYear
    Click Link    ${clickElement}

Get Datepicker MonthYear
    [Documentation]     Return current month + year from datepicker
    [Return]    ${monthyear}
    ${month}=   Get Element Text  //*/div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']//*/div[@class='ui-datepicker-title']/span[@class='ui-datepicker-month']
    ${year}=    Get Element Text  //*/div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']//*/div[@class='ui-datepicker-title']/span[@class='ui-datepicker-year']
    ${monthyear}=   Catenate    ${month}  ${year}
```

And then use **Select Datepicker Date** keyword with required arguments in your Test Cases.

Comment: What should be the `${clickElement}` argument here ?

Answer (score 0):

This Below link is a working solution to use RobotFramework to choose date from datepicker

[datepicker_robotFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56558626/selecting-readonly-datepickers-by-using-robotframework-and-input-date-into-it)

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer.  However please show the exact solution (content) that you refer in the link into your own post.