# Selecting Readonly Datepickers by using RobotFramework and input date into it

Tags: javascript, selenium, datepicker, robotframework

Here is a working solution for choosing a date from a datepicker using robot framework.
Datepickers are basically input tags but some of them have an extra attribute "readonly" due to which it becomes difficult to add date into it.

1)First Check if datepicker is readonly or not.
-inspect the page , locate the tag and check.
if it is not read only we can directly use the below code to under previous day date.

```
${Yeterday_Date} =      Get Current Date    result_format=%d/%m/%Y    increment=-1 day
Input Text    ${locator}    ${Yeterday_Date}
```

2)If it has an attribute readonly, remove that attribute and input date into it.

```
Execute Javascript          document.querySelector("locator").removeAttribute("readonly");
Execute Javascript          document.querySelector("locator").removeAttribute("onchange");
Execute Javascript          document.querySelector("locator").setAttribute("value", "${Yeterday_Date}");
```

Some datepickers have an onchange attribute which is invoked after readonly attribute is removed, so its better to remove both the attributes.

Comment: So, this isn't a question, but some kind of tutorial? If so, don't remove the onchange attribute - you're modifying your SUT, and impairing any functionality on the input that depends to kick when you've set a value.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question but a blog post.

Comment: It does not trigger any underlying functions if there is any any when we select/change the date.